# Understanding Algebraic Multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you help me understand this statement:

*An eigenvalue c has algebraic multiplicity $k$ if $(t-c)^k$ is the highest power of $(t-c)$ that divides the characteristic polynomial.*

I am not sure, what does $t$ stand for. I have lifted this statement from the first statement under Algebraic Multiplicity heading from this [link](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/eigen.html)

Comment: $t$ is the variable in the characteristic polynomial. The characteristic polynomial is a *polynomial*, computed as $\det(tI-A)$, where $A$ is the matrix of the linear transformation. You may be used to different notation; just substitute the name of the variable you are used to.

Comment: Thanks I suspected as much. Is there a possibility you can sneak in some help in how to prove it.

Comment: How to prove what? It's a *definition*. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: It looks like the definition should read "... c has algebraic multiplicity k if k is the highest power of ...".  Perhaps it's a typo...

Comment: @Andrew: How so? It says "$c$ has algebraic multiplicity $k$ if $(t-c)^k$ is the highest power of $(t-c)$ that divides the characteristic polynomial." It seems perfectly correct to me.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're right, I misread it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue is its multiplicity as a root of the characteristic polynomial.

Then a root $c$ of $P(t)$ has multiplicity $\mu$ if $\mu$ is the highest integer such as $(t-c)^\mu$ divides $P(t)$.